# Why transversing the list for LinkedList and Arraylist takes same time?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

Why would the big O for Arraylist and LinkedList for this code would be same O(MN)?

PS: I do not fully understand this code. Any explanation would be appreciated.

```
public static int Count( List<Integer> lst1, List<Integer> lst2) {
    Iterator<Integer> itr1 = lst1.iterator();

    int count=0;
    while ( itr1.hasNext() ) {
        Integer x = itr1.next();
        Iterator<Integer> itr2 = lst2.iterator();
        while (itr2.hasNext())
            if (x.equals(itr2.next()))
                count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that it takes the "same time"?  As to the code, it has nothing to do with the question in the title, and questions of the form "please explain this code" are off-topic.

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry for causing confusion. There is a question that asks based  on this code determine the big O of it running in ArrayList and it running in LinkedList. Then after my classmates explanations I realized that the answer for both is O(MN) not I wonder why. I hope it is more clear now. Let me know if there is more questions. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To traversing both the list would take same time complexity.

But deletion is faster in LinkedList compared to ArrayList.
Because ArrayList work on index basis and LinkedList works on address tracking.